# Convention for serif font

Tags: font, windows-phone-7

In the design guidelines for Windows Phone, you are encouraged to use the font Segoe WP for the most of your UIs. Segoe WP is a sans-serif typeface.

Is there a convention or guideline for which **serif** font to use?

From the list of built-in fonts in Windows Phone, I can find two candidates: **Georgia** and **Times New Roman**.

I am aware of that using serif font on screen is considered bad by many people. But if my designer told me to use the default serif font of the platform, which should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft recommends using the Cambria font if you have to use a serif font. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553415.aspx

Comment: My source of information, the book Windows Phone Unleashed, didn't include Cambria. If I understand correctly, Windows Phone 7.x didn't include Cambria, but it was added for Windows Phone 8.